# What are the different functions available in the yocto just like - do_compile_append?

Tags: yocto

I am looking for the different functions available in the yocto just like do_compile_append()?
Also, when is the do_compile_append() is invoked by the yocto. I am looking into the in depth manual documentation on such functions. Are there any examples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto has extensive documentation. Tasks and dependencies in general as well as the standard tasks like `do_compile()` are defined in the [Reference Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#normal-recipe-build-tasks). The function override style ("_append" and "_prepend") is explained in the [Bitbake Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#shell-functions). What exactly happens during a do_compile depends on the specific recipe of course.

The [Mega Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html) contains all of the Yocto documentation in a single html file -- very useful for quick searches but it's already far longer than most novels so not suitable for reading front-to-back.